# How to remove hover/clicked effect in pygtk?

Tags: python, python-2.7, button, pygtk

I want to remove or turn off this hover and clicked effect on button in pygtk. Do you have any ideas? I couldn't find anything useful here [gtk.Button](http://pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkbutton.html)

I am talking about this:

[Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNr8h.png)

[Hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL6s2.png)

[Clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlvr3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Do you really want a button? The main distinction between buttons and labels are those effects (labels don't generate events, but you can make them do so by packing them into a Gtk.EventBox)

-Here's how to disable the events that cause the effects in first place:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  test_inert_button.py
#
#  Copyright 2017 John Coppens <john@jcoppens.com>
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
#


import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.connect("destroy", lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())
        self.set_size_request(400, 300)

        btn1 = Gtk.Button("One - inert button")
        btn2 = Gtk.Button("Two - active button")

        btn1.connect("enter-notify-event", self.on_leave)
        btn1.connect("button-press-event", self.on_leave)

        vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        vbox.pack_start(btn1, False, False, 0)
        vbox.pack_start(btn2, False, False, 0)

        self.add(vbox)
        self.show_all()

    def on_leave(self, btn, event):
        return True

    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()


def main(args):
    mainwdw = MainWindow()
    mainwdw.run()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

The on_leave method's `return True` tells the default handler that events are handled so it won't do the effects. The top button `One` doesn't react, the bottom one still does.

Comment: It should work if you have the necessary module installed for introspection. Try to `import gi` in python. You'll also need a (more or less ) recent version of Gtk which installs the tables for introspection (which is probably the case). Easiest way to test this - execute the 3 lines from `import gi` from the above program. And consider upgrading to Python 3... It's way less complicated than you think!

Comment: Yeah, but I have to work with old pygtk and 7 years old arch-based system and I can't install additional modules so... You see.

Comment: Just ran the program under my installation of Python 2.7, and it worked without any change.

Comment: BTW, I suspect this should work with `pygtk` too. The methods I use in the program above are available there too. I don't have amd updated `pygtk` installed. Just do `import pygtk` instead of the `gi` code/